# JQuery Validator plugin: Remote call not working

Tags: jquery, validation, remote-validation

I'm trying to validate an user name with a remote validation.
here is the js code

```
$('#form_reg').validate({
    rules: {
     username: {
        minlength: 6,
        required: true,
        remote: { url:"validate_usr.php", async:false }
      },
 },
highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
  });
```

and the php file

```
<?php
 include("bd_conex_mysql.php");

if (!empty($_REQUEST['username']))
{
$usrname = $_REQUEST['username'];
$checkname = mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) FROM cuentas WHERE CtaUsr = '".$usrname."'");  
if($checkname->fetch_row() > 0){
    echo 'false';
}
else{
    echo 'true';
}
}
else
{
 echo 'false';
}

?>
```

It keeps accepting the input even if the username is already taken.

I've changed the php file to

```
    echo 'false';
    ?>
```

and keeps validating the input.

Comment: Why would the returned SQL resource be 0? You should probably fetch the result with something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no more support for mysql_* functions, they are officially deprecated, no longer maintained and will be removed in the future. You should update your code with PDO or MySQLi to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

`mysql_query` returns a `resource` rather than the result set.  So `$checkname > 0` will always be true. You need to then fetch with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

You should change the query command to `mysqli_query`.  And check the results of `$checkname->fetch_row()`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Examine the results of $checkname->fetch_row() with `var_dump`, it is going to be an array.  So you want to check the value of the key for the count.

Comment: ok. Now it works if I access directly, but keeps validating the input in the form. Maybe is the true/false format

Comment: Check the response from the server in your console or firebug, see what the actual response is coming back.